# File creation time via PHP (or something similar)

Tags: php, file

I'm looping through a directory and getting all the files using glob(). Is there a way to order the elements of the resulting array by the date/time they were created? Currently I'm using filemtime(), but that assumes that they were never edited.

Cheers!

Comment: it depends on the OS, but on unix based systems, the creation time isn't available, only the modification time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try the following:

```
$array = glob("*.txt");
usort($array, function($a, $b) {
    $aTime = filectime($a);
    $bTime = filectime($b);
    if ($aTime < $bTime) {
        return -1;
    } elseif ($aTime > $bTime) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
});
```

That passes an anonymous function to allow user-defined sorting of an array. The function this time, checks and sorts depending upon the creation time (windows) / inode change time(linux) of the files returned by glob.

Hope this helps.

ise

Comment: Cheers! That worked perfectly, just had to reverse $a and $b (I wanted the most recent on top, should have specified that). Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filectime.php

May be a bit closer to what you need. It's still updated when edited, but not the contents.. only the meta-data.

Comment: Interesting, mind elaborating the difference between filemtime and filectime? I don't really understand.

Answer (score 0):

Many file systems don't keep any information about file creation date. On these you can try using filectime.